# implementation of strstr() function

Tags: c

The code says at many places "invalid indirection".Please help.

```
   int main()
    {

        char *s1,*s2,*position;
        printf("Enter string:\n");
        gets(s1);
        printf("Enter word to find:\n");
        gets(s2);
        *position=ststr(*s1,*s1);
        if(*position)
        printf("word is found at %c loc\n",*position);
        else
        printf("word not found");
        getch();
        return 0;

    }

char *strstr(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int flag=1;
    char i,j;
    for(i=0; ;i++)
    {
        if(*s1[i]==*s2[0])
        for(j=i;*s2;j++)
        {
            if(*s1[j]!=*s2[j])
            flag=0;
        }

    }
    if(flag)
    return i;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh my god, it's full of stars!

Comment: You have any other way for that :P ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, `s1` and `s2` in main have not been initialized to point anywhere meaningful.  Either declare them as static arrays, or allocate memory to them at runtime using `malloc()` or `calloc()`:

```
#define SIZE 20 // or some number big enough to hold your input
...
char s1[SIZE], s2[SIZE], *position; // s1 and s2 declared statically
```

Second, **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets()`; it *will* introduce a point of failure in your program. Use `fgets()` instead:

```
if (fgets(s1, sizeof s1, stdin) != NULL)
  // process s1
else
  // check for EOF or error on read
```

**EDIT**

And like everyone else has pointed out, your comparison in the `strstr()` function needs to be either

```
*s1 == *s2
```

*or*

```
s1[i] == s2[i]
```

but first you need to deal with allocating your buffers in main properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(*s1[i]==*s2[0])
```

is such an example where my gcc complains:

```
error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)
```

if `s1` is a pointer to `char`, `s1[i]` is a char. So you can't `dereference` it any more (with the `*`), i.e. `s1[i]` does not point to anything any more.

Try

```
if(s1[i]==s2[0])
```

instead.

---

You should also change the return value of `strstr`: you return an integer where you declare to return a pointer to a character. So try returning `s1+i` instead.

---

This here:

```
for(j=i;*s2;j++)
```

probably does not what you want. You're not advancing the pointer `s2` anywhere in the loop, in fact you're just testing whether `s2[0]` (which is the same as `*s2`) is zero for each iteration. If `s2` isn't the empty string, this loop will never terminate.

Comment: I see that I missed a word in the response, I'll update this. My gcc complains about the return statement in strstr: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast . Indeed, you should return a pointer to a char (s1 + i or equivalently &(s1[i]) ), not an integer (like i).

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems I'm noticing is whenever you do `*s1[j]`.  The asterisk is dereferencing the array, and so is the `[]` notation.

`s[i]` really means `*(s + i)`, so you don't have to dereference it again.  The way you have it would read `**(s + i)`, and since it's a single pointer you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include "stdio.h"
char *strstr(char *str, char *substr)
{
    int len = strlen(substr);
    char *ref = substr;
    while(*str && *ref)
    {
        if (*str++ == *ref)
        {
            ref++;
        }
        if(!*ref)
        {
            return (str - len);
        }
        if (len == (ref - substr))
        {
            ref = substr;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("%s \n", strstr("TEST IS NOT DONE", "IS NOT"));
}
```

Comment: Normally in SO it is not a good practice to present just a piece of code without providing some explanation for it. Please provide some information about your respond so it will be understood  easier by others.

Answer (score 1):

```
         if(*s1[j]!=*s2[j])
```

- `*s1` means "the character where s1 is pointing".
- `s1[j]` means "`*(s1+j)`" or "the character j positions after where s1 is pointing"

You have to use one or the other; not both.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* my_strstr(char *s2, char *s1)
{
  int i, j;
  int flag = 0;

  if ((s2 == NULL || s1 == NULL)) return NULL;

  for( i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (s2[i] == s1[0])
    {
      for (j = i; ; j++)
      {
        if (s1[j-i] == '\0'){ flag = 1; break;}
        if (s2[j] == s1[j-i]) continue;
        else break;
      }
    }
    if (flag == 1) break;
  }

  if (flag) return (s2+i);
  else return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  char s2[] = "This is the statement";
  char s1[] = "the";
  char *temp;

  temp = my_strstr(s2,s1);

  printf("%s\n",temp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please comment your answer also, so others understand better why this code is answer to the question?

Comment: The `flag` variable and the `continue` and `break` stuff in the inner loop are unnecessary. The body of the inner loop could be just `{ if (s1[j-i] == '\0') return(s2 + i); if (s2[j] != s1[j-i]) break; }`, or thereabouts.